# Troubleshooting an old MATLAB script: "Not enough input arguments"

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm currently going back through old MATLAB university assignments. It's been a while since I used MATLAB, and I'm having trouble figuring out the error with this script that presumably ran OK when I wrote it and submitted it ~4 years ago-- my submission has the correct plots below the code from the output. Maybe MATLAB syntax has changed slightly?

The assignment was running SIR (infectious disease) simulations using the ODE solver. Here's the code below:

```
%%FUNCTION:
function rhs = SIR_rhs_seasonal(t,u,p,D,G)
%Right-hand side of SIR model
%Assumes 52 weeks in a year

B=((15*(1/7))/3000000)*(1+p*cos(2*pi*t/365));

S = u(1);
E = u(2);
I = u(3);
R = u(4);

rhs = [ -B*S*I; (B*S*I)-(D*E); (D*E)-(G*I); G*I ];

%%ODE SOLVER:
%% parameters
tend = 700;
D=1/7;
G=1/7;
p=.1;
N=3000000

%% initial condition
u = [ N*.99; N*0; N*.01; N*0 ];

%% solve ODE
[T,U] = ode45(@(t,u) SIR_rhs_seasonal(t,u,p,D,G),[0:0.1:tend],u);

%% plot results
figure(1);
plot(T,U(:,1),'b',T,U(:,2),'r',T,U(:,3),'k',T,U(:,4),'g');
axis([0 10 0 3000000]);
xlabel('time = weeks');
ylabel('population');
title('susceptibles (blue), latent (red), infectious (black), recovered/removed (green)');

figure(2);
plot(T,U(:,2)./(U(:,2)+U(:,3)),'b')
axis([0 tend -.25 1]);
xlabel('time = days');
ylabel('E(t)/(E(t)+I(t))');
title('Latent proportion of infectives');
```

The error currently get is:

> SIRmodel2 Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in SIRmodel2 (line 6)
>   B=((15*(1/7))/3000000)*(1+p*cos(2*pi*t/365));

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Why does your error say `pcos(2*pi*t/365))` and not `p*cos(2*pi*t/365))`? Is this right?

Comment: have you redefined `cos` somehow?

Comment: My error says p*cos... this is how it's written in in my text box, but somehow the * isn't showing up in the final post.

Comment: Fixed (that `*` needed escaping as `\*`)

Comment: This function takes a bunch of arguments.  Are you supplying them when you call the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to verify first:

- The error message indicates you use a function `SIRmodel2`, however the function printed in your post is called `SIR_rhs_seasonal`. Is the file named `SIRmodel2.m`, i.e. is this really the function that is executing?

If this is the function that is executing, then the error is thrown at line 6 since it is the first line some of the input arguments, namely `p` and `t`, of the function are used. Likely you called the function without specifying these inputs.

How do you call the function?

You can also verify the situation by putting a break point at line 6 (move cursor to line 6 and hit F12) and running the code. It will stop before executing the line. Now hover with the mouse over the variables `p` and `t`. At least one of them will not be defined.

Comment: Indeed, I had tried this earlier: changing the function name to the filename, running it, and now I get the error "Undefined function or variable 't'."

If my memory serves me, though, I'm trying to use ode45 to solve this ode and plot the results over time, t. 

Maybe I'm just using the function call incorrectly? I just want to define an ODE, give the parameters, and then plot it.

Comment: Actually, I just solved this using your help. I had the old MATLAB files, and realized that the function was saved in its own file with variable declarations, and the parameters and the plots were in another file. I ran the non-function file, which calls the function file and executes correctly. I didn't realize you can't seem to define a function and call it in the same script in MATLAB?

Comment: That feature was introduced only recently, either in 16b or 17a. Did not make use of it myself, though.